# Issue with centering a slider

Tags: jquery, css

I cant seem to figure out what the problem is with my homepage slider on http://www.ferngrottokauai.com/ When you view it on IE it is centered as it should be. But it is pushed to the left on all other browsers. My slider container code is:

```
.slider_container {
    width: 920px;
    margin: auto;
    clear: both;
    background: url("images/shadow_top.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    padding: 30px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `table` (shudder) that is being used to contain the slider isnt centering.

Add the following to your stylesheet and it should center:

```
#dnn_ContentPane .SimpleContainer{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```